# Page doesn't redirect after Facebook login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code ([codeigniter-facebook-php-sdk-v4](https://github.com/appleboy/codeigniter-facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/libraries/lib_login.php)) to connect my controller to Facebook login. `Mycontroller`:

```
public function index() {
    //load views
    $this->load->view('pages/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/index'); //contains a href of mycontroller/facebook_login
    $this->load->view('pages/footer');
}

public function facebook_login() {
    $fb_data = $this->lib_facebook->facebook();

    if (isset($fb_data['me'])) {
         //save fb user data
    }
}
```

After, the data is saved, the browser is still `mycontroller/facebook_login` page. I want it to redirect it to the `index` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
>
> If your web app uses Facebook Login on the back-end, you'll need to
>   redirect your visitors to a URL at Facebook to initiate a login
>   request. Facebook then redirects the user to your apps callback URL,
>   providing session data. This helper class will generate the login URL
>   for you, and can process and validate the data from Facebook,
>   returning a FacebookSession on success.

Remember when you set your callback URL ? Yes, change that before you do the request.

```
// change the url before you make the request
$desired_url = 'url_desired'; // set the url you want the user to be redirected after logging in
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($desired_url);
```

And then you can simply use

```
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
```

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks. Also, I could I get rid of the URL params? in the URL?

Comment: No you can't, I tried and searched, it seems a facebook API bug.

Comment: Not one that I'm aware of at least. I've seen others using URI manipulation, regex, and etc.